# When should one use intval and when int

Tags: php

What is the better option:

```
// Option 1:
$intValue = (int) $numericValue;

// Option 2:
$intValue = intval($numericValue);
```

Is there any difference between these two lines, and which should be used in which situation?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. `intval` is slower than casting to `int` (it's a function)
2. `intval` can accept a base if its first parameter is a string

Since the second item is really obscure, objectively we should say that `intval` is simply "worse".

However, personally I like reading `intval($var)` better than `(int)$var` (the latter may also require wrapping in additional parens) and since if you are converting to `int` inside a loop you are definitely doing something wrong, I use `intval`.

Comment: Downvoter: Help me make the answer better. Thank you.

Comment: To address point #1, here's a speed comparison of the two: https://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/05/13/php-casting-vs-intval/

Answer (score 5):

All behaviour explained here along with GOTCHAS...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php