# How can I take an id from the url in php and use it like a number?

Tags: php, casting, integer, uri

I have a url that will look as follows.

```
post/:id
```

I am exploding the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`;

and I need to make the `$uri[2]` is numerical so I can do things like

`$next = $uri[2]++;`

I have tried `is_numeric` but of course the `request_uri` is a string (broken into an array of strings).

Can I type cast in php to integer?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting

Comment: I know PHP is dynamically typed, but its always a string, I need to cast to integer.

Comment: Yeees... and the section that I linked to "Type Casting" explains how to do it.

Comment: Hamish if you wanna make that an answer Although David is right, you did get there first so you kinda deserve the credit.

Comment: No, that's fine, I didn't post an answer, although I would recommend to David that he should link to documentation where possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$int = (int) $uri[2];
```

You just have to convert from string to integer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `intval()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php?

`int intval(mixed $var [, int $base = 10 ])`

"Returns the integer value of var, using the specified base for the conversion (the default is base 10). intval() should not be used on objects, as doing so will emit an E_NOTICE level error and return 1."

**UPDATE**

Having wondered what the difference between `(int) $string` and `intval($string)` is, there are some interesting comments on previous SO questions;

- `(int)` is upto 600% faster
- `intval` makes it easier to typecast within other functions
- `intval` has the benefit of changing base (although this is fairly obscure)
- `intval` is more readable (tho this is obviously very subjective)

  1. [Is there any particular difference between intval and casting to int - `(int) X`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912599/is-there-any-particular-difference-between-intval-and-int)
  2. [When should one use intval and when int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339590/when-should-one-use-intval-and-when-int)
  3. http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/05/13/php-casting-vs-intval/

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify both [David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11679512/881551) and [ChrisW](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11679515/881551) are correct. Those are [two](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) [ways](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) of doing it as described at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting

```
<?php

$str = '100';

var_dump( $str ); // string(3) "100"

// http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php
var_dump( intval($str) ); // int(100)

// http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php
var_dump( (int) $str ); // int(100)

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just take it as a number from url passing argument in as a `$_GET` request.

Or pass through as a `$_POST` request.

But in the case of $_POST request we cann't pass the value to url. if you want you can using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and convert to `(int) $_GET['pid']`.