# Convert string to integer?

Tags: php, variables, integer

I'm pulling results from an XML file and one of the values (an actual numeric ID) is being read as a string.  The value is trimmed and has no whitespace.   I observed this by checking with is_numeric:

```
        if (!is_numeric($id))
        {
            echo "<p>$id is NOT numeric";
        } else {
            echo "<p>$id is numeric";
        }
```

The response of a variable 643394 is:

```
643394 is NOT numeric
```

PHP has a function to convert an integer to a string (strtoint), but I didn't find a function to go the other way (inttostr).

Is it possible to convert string "1234" to integer 1234?

Comment: intval() will convert it for you or (int) $id;

Comment: There must be some other characters that are part of your string because `is_numeric('643394')` should return `true`. What does `var_dump($id);` give you?

Comment: Hang on, are you trying to convert an int to a string or vice versa?

Comment: String to int.  Double check post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cast your string to an integer explicitly

```
$id = (int) $id;
```

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: May I ask what the benefit of using this advantage is over using `intval()`?

Comment: @VictorKilo - According to https://wiki.phpbb.com/Best_Practices:PHP, using a function for conversion is slightly slower than directly casting. For a further explanation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339590/when-should-one-use-intval-and-when-int

Answer (score 1):

String to integer conversion can be done with intval($id) or force an integer type with (int)$id

Answer (score 0):

This is will help you:

```
$id = $id + 0;
```